# Why isn't a private var in Swift struct available in #if'd init for that struct?

Tags: swift, macos, struct, ncurses

While doing some research on ncurses and how to use it in Swift, I took a look at [IOGUI](https://github.com/ilk33r/IOGUI).

It wouldn't compile properly, so I began clearing warnings and errors.

That's when I came across what may be some Swift subtleness that I'm unaware of.

> Note: I'm not discussing compilation errors below. This question is specific to the parsing done by Xcode to indicate warnings and errors in the code editor.

Referring to the following struct:

```swift
public struct MenuWidget {

    var widgetRows: Int
    // CUT
    private var startRow: Int

#if os(Linux)
    public init(startRow: Int, widgetSize: Int, choices: [GUIMenuChoices], delegate: @escaping MenuChoicesSelectionDelegate, mainWindow: UnsafeMutablePointer<WINDOW>) {

        self.startRow = startRow
        // CUT
        initWindows()
    }
#else
    public init(startRow: Int, widgetSize: Int, choices: [GUIMenuChoices], delegate: @escaping MenuChoicesSelectionDelegate, mainWindow: OpaquePointer) {

        self.startRow = startRow
        // CUT
        initWindows()
    }
#endif

    // CUT
} // END STRUCT
```

Within the `#if os(Linux)` section, `self.startRow` is marked as inaccessible from that scope.

Yet in the `#else`, there is no error indicated. `widgetRows` is accessible in both the `#if` and `#else`

If I remove private from the `startRow` declaration, then it's fine in both scopes. But that makes the variable `internal` and makes it accessible outside of the struct, which is incorrect.

It could also just be the behavior of the Swift `#if` construct that I'm not familiar with.

I've searched the usual places, including here at SO. Nothing similar deals with this particular scenario, at least not with the search terms I used.

Any hints or tips would be appreciated.

P.S. If you want to check out the [IOGUI](https://github.com/ilk33r/IOGUI) source, I'm specifically referring to lines 41 and 78-100 (inclusive) of MenuWidget.swift.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an `if` construct; it's an `#if` construct. That means that only one of the `#if` / `#endif` blocks even compiles. The other could be complete nonsense for all the Swift compiler cares; the compiler never even sees it. That is what conditional compilation means. So, if you are not on Linux, you have no way of knowing how the code inside the `#if` part behaves. The code would be just the same if it said this:

```
#if os(Linux)
    public init(startRow: Int, widgetSize: Int, choices: [GUIMenuChoices], delegate: @escaping MenuChoicesSelectionDelegate, mainWindow: UnsafeMutablePointer<WINDOW>) {
        zampabalooie and a hot-cha-cha
    }
#else
    public init(startRow: Int, widgetSize: Int, choices: [GUIMenuChoices], delegate: @escaping MenuChoicesSelectionDelegate, mainWindow: OpaquePointer) {
        self.startRow = startRow
        // CUT
        initWindows()
    }
#endif
```

If you are not on Linux, that will compile just fine — and that doesn't entitle you to start drawing conclusions about Swift's knowledge of some amazing "zampabalooie" or its sudden use of spaces between terms.

And conversely, if you *are* on Linux, you have no way of knowing how the code inside the `#else` part behaves.

Comment: Right. Sorry, my question wasn't clear. I was referring to Xcode 10.1 indicating that the reference within the #if block isn't accessible. I've updated my question with a note about what I'm referring to.

Comment: But I stand by what I said. It isn't going to say this for _both_ blocks, because one block isn't even compiled.

Comment: Also I can't reproduce what you're describing based on what you've said so far. Can you provide an MCVE? I don't want to download the whole 3rd party code just for this one thing. Besides, you say it doesn't compile as is.